# WKHTMLTOPDF Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis, wkhtmltopdf

i have a really simple asp.net (.net 4) web app.
Its a simple Hello World web form app running on WinServer and IIS6 (tried also 7).
Authentication is "Windows authentication"
I want to convert it with WKHTMLTOPDF to PDF.
But i always get an error.
When i allow Anonymous access it works.
If not i get the error.

wkhtmltopdf.exe --username domain\DELETED --password DELETED http://****/index2.html d:\tmp\test.pdf

Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done

Exit with code 1 due to http error: 1299

The pdf created tells me: "The function requested is not supported"

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.

You can add userName and password as options to WKHTMLtoPDF but then you need everybodys passwords which makes that worthless.

But there is a workaround. You can use windows impersonation in IIS and therefore bypass this issue.

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on msdn to configure it.

*Edit*

You need to activate NTML v1 on server, see Cutter1703 comment below.

Comment: Passing username and password as option did not work.
Will give impersonation a try.

Comment: Also tried impersonation.
Tried it only with impersonation true and also with adding credentials to web.config. Both failed with the pdf creation error:
Error: Authentication Required

Comment: I dont have the code, anymore. But I know I have done it with windows impersonation. But I remember that it was a bitch getting it to work. Make sure that the impersonation works by just creating a page that outputs the username. And then you need to make sure that the appPool too has the correct credentials.

Comment: Looks like it works now. Had also to allow NTML v1 on server
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/903071

Comment: Please tag my answer and I will update it with the information, or better yet, write your own answer with full information, and preferably the web.config changes the next guy needs to do.

Comment: You could also have one reserved account that has access to everything for wkhtmltopdf needs. Also another option would be to use a cookie which you can feed into wkhtmltopdf (if you'd be using Forms auth).